# How can you set a list as a query paramter?

Tags: java, list, jpa, entities

I got this code with a little help from chattgpt. But it is not working. It always say it needs a int:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList for parameter list with expected type of int from query string SELECT s.studygroupid FROM SubjectStudyGroup s WHERE s.subjectid IN (:list).
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:946)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:609)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:69)
at Testen.Testen.main(Testen.java:27)

Can you explain why it does not take the list-paramter or how he will accept the parameter.

```
  private static EntityManager em = null;
  private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    open();
    List<Integer> subjectIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s.studygroupid FROM SubjectStudyGroup s WHERE s.subjectid IN (:list)");
    query.setParameter("list", subjectIds);
    List<Integer> studyGroupIds = query.getResultList();
    close();

}

private static void open()
{
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

private static void close()
{
    if(em != null)
    {
        em.close();
        em = null;
    }

    if(emf != null)
    {
        emf.close();
        em = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*But it is not working. It always say it needs a int.*" - Please [edit] the post and add the compiler error / stack trace.

Comment: Chatgpt's answer can only be used as a reference, most of the code related is wrong

Comment: @时间只会一直走 This answer is spring-specific since it uses `SimpleJdbcTemplate`. OP uses "pure" JPA.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is to replace this: (:list) with :list. Now it is functioning.